# Date Time Function - Teradata

Tags: teradata

I am trying to convert this time '2012-6-17 09:50:3.000000'
I want to remove the additional zeros from here , this date is US time zone I want to convert it to local time zone.

I tried using datepart(2), current_date functions - could not find the suitable solution to it.
Also I tried using various date functions methods following youtube but could not get sutable solution.

Kindly help.

Comment: "Date functions" work on date or perhaps timestamp (date/time) data and this appears to be a string. Something like `REGEXP_REPLACE('2012-06-17 09:50:3.000000','\b([0-9]}\b,'0\1')` will add the leading zeros you need to be able to CAST it to TIMESTAMP.  Without an explicit time zone offset the database will assume the session, user, or system time zone. If you know the numeric time zone offset of the data you can append to the string and use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type. Then either adjust yourself with an INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE difference or use AT '+05:30' in your SELECT for IST.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you tried and give example of what you see versus what you want to see. Or delete this question and post a new one with more detail.

Comment: Hello Fred,

I am looking to add get the time difference in this, and also get it in my local time zone, If the difference goes beyond 24 hrs let it calculate in days
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-06 03:23:55.000000' - TIMESTAMP '2021-10-06 03:22:31.000000' AS duration, Can you help me here

Comment: `assume this date is US time zone` - you don't know if it's a US time zone, or which one it is?  Please don't put clarification/additional info in comments, edit your post and put the new info into it.

Comment: Hello Andrew,
I have edited the time zone it is US and I want to convert to India local time,SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-06 03:23:55.000000' - TIMESTAMP '2021-10-06 03:22:31.000000' will be glad to have a solution with time difference and convertion to local time zone ies IST.

Comment: There is no "US time zone" per se. There are 4 different standard time zones (Eastern, Central, Mountain, and Pacific) for the contiguous 48 US states which all observe daylight saving adjustment, except the state of Arizona (outside of Navajo Nation sovereign territory) does not observe daylight saving. To convert the time, you need to know the specific source time zone offset - which for daylight saving depends on the date. If you have two timestamps and want the difference as an interval, something such as `(timestamp2 - timestamp1 day(4) to second)` will do that